# Linux MS SQL ODBC Driver for MySQL Workbench iODBC

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, odbc, mysql-workbench

I am running MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 12.04.  MySQL workbench cannot use FreeTDS for migration of MSSQL 2000 to MYSQL, it wants to use iODBC.  I cannot find a deb/ubuntu MS SQL 2000 ODBC connector that I can use with iODBC.

All the documentation *assumes* you are running MySQL Workbench under Windows.  I tried that, but had too many issues.  Based on 3 days to googeling, trial and error, I think it will work better with MySQL Workbench running the migration from Ubunto instead of Windows.

Does anyone know of an ODBC driver for Ubuntu that will work with MySQL Workbench/iODBC?

Thanks!

JR

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: iODBC is **NOT** a driver, is a driver manager. FreeTDS is a driver and you need both to use migration wizard. All detailed instructions how to setup you can find in link below:

- [Installing a driver for Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase ASE in Linux and Mac](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/02/installing-a-driver-for-microsoft-sql-server-and-sybase-ase-in-linux-and-mac/)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL migration forum contains a number of sticky links to various resources that may help you with your task.

- [How-To, Blog post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?104,562787,562787#msg-562787)
- [List of links to ODBC drivers for various RDBMSes (and MS Access)](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?104,562701,562701#msg-562701)

Comment: Note that the "list of links" contains only one ref to Linux, and that is a technet article about it - no Download Link.  The 'how to' is as the OP described, for Windows users.  The OPs question (and mine) is "Does anyone know of an ODBC driver for Ubuntu that will work with MySQL Workbench/iODBC?"  My ODBC Drivers tab is empty in the ODBC Administrator in MySQL-Workbench.